# How to properly populate InetSocketAddress

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I am trying to populate the Host header. I have inserted dummy data for the my example but I am wondering it I am populating this correctly. When examine the value of address it appears unlike I would expect. I would expect [domain]:[port] but I am seeing [domain]/[ip address]:[port]. Is this normal?

Here is the line I am using

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("sample.com", 8080);
```

Here is the variable value afterwards:

```
address = {InetSocketAddress} sample.com/173.230.129.147:8080
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is normal. `InetSocketAddress` tries to resolve the host name to an IP address automatically.

From the [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html):

> This class implements an IP Socket Address (IP address + port number) It can also be a pair (hostname + port number), in which case **an attempt will be made to resolve the hostname**.

If you want to create the InetSocketAddress without resolving the host name to an IP address, you can use the `createUnresolved` factory method.

```
jshell> InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("example.com", 8080);
$20 ==> example.com:8080
```